# How to get image url from PHAsset for iOS 13

Tags: swift4, ios13, xcode11, phasset

As no longer `PHImageFileURLKey` is given, how i can get image reference url for picked image!

Using `PHImageFileUTIKey` key i was able to get the file name.

I tried to play around `PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: assets[0])` but still there is no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: { (input, info) in
    if let input = input {
        print(input.fullSizeImageURL) // file:///xxx    
    }
})
```

this is how i was able to get full imageURL.